# Alternative to eval to execute functions

Tags: javascript, eval

if i have this code:

```
var x = "alert('eval is evil')";
```

Can i execute this without eval?

I searched other posts and found nothing for this situation.

Comment: Do you mean is there a way to execute a string as code without using `eval`?

Comment: What type of application are you building? I would avoid eval if possible

Comment: Your question does not make clear what you are trying to do - what is your use case for such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add it to the `Function` constructor and then call that

```
var x = new Function("alert('this is not much better')");
x();
```

however, that is not much better. Evaluating javascript either way is prone to errors and in some cases insecure and generally, if you need eval in your code your app design is wrong

Answer (score 1):

There is no other function in javascript you can use to execute random javascript code instead of eval, however the only other option is to append it to the page via `<script>` like so

```
var x = "alert('eval is evil')",
    script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = x;
script.type = 'text/javascript';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what `eval` was designed to do. The point is, you should never write code that necessitates the use of `eval`; 99.99% of the time you're doing it wrong and there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on setting `x` to a string, there's no simple way to avoid `eval`.<sup>*</sup> However, you can do this instead:

```
var x = function() { alert('eval is evil'); };
```

Or, in modern JS engines:

```
var x = alert.bind(null, 'eval is evil');
```

Then you can simply execute `x`:

```
x();
```

<sup>*</sup><sub>There are techniques to avoiding `eval`. For instance, you can add a `script` tag to the document containing the text that you want executed.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`eval` is basically an embedded JS interpreter, if you're not happy with the build-in interpreter, you can program your own. It can be complicated or easy, depending on which subset of the language you're going to support. For the given code example, that's fairly easy:

```
re=/(\w+)\('(.+?)'\)/
code="alert('eval is evil')"
m=code.match(re)
window[m[1]](m[2]) // works
```

For serious work, consider using a parser generator, like jison or peg.js.